# Рей или рея?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Встречаю в литературе то один вариант написания, то другой. Речь, понятное дело, идет о поперечном брусе на мачте парусного корабля.
Почему-то чаще встречаю вариант "рей", хотя на слуху все-таки пиратское "Всех на рею!" 
Так как все-таки правильно, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Я полагал, что это от англ. "ray" - "луч"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересно получается.
рея I. ре́•я. 1. морск. подвижной поперечный брус, подвешиваемый за середину к мачте и служащий для привязывания к нему паруса на парусных судах и для подачи сигналов на судах с механическими двигателям.
Ре́я (др.-греч. Ῥέα, эпич. Ῥείη) — титанида в древнегреческой мифологии, мать олимпийских богов. Дочь Урана и Геи. Супруга и сестра титана Кроноса, мать богини домашнего очага Гестии, богини полей и плодородия Деметры, богини семей и родов Геры, бога подземного царства Аида...

Значение слова Рей по Ожегову:
Рей - Подвижной поперечный брус на мачте, служащий для крепления парусов, для установки антенн и для подъема сигналов

Рей в Энциклопедическом словаре:
Рей - город (6 в. до н. э. - 13 в. н. э.) в Иране, вблизи Тегерана. В 9-13вв. центр производства художественной керамики. Башенный мавзолей Тогрулбека (1139).

Answer (score 3):

Видимо, слово сменило грамматический род в процессе адаптации в новом для него русском языке.. Исторически был мужской, сейчас женский.
Это бывает с иностранными словами. Несколько необычно только то, что процесс этот несколько затянулся... Но тоже не столь уж редкий случай...

Больше тут исследовать нечего.

Comment: О как...

Так уж и нечего?
рейка, рейс, рейсшина, рейтузы, рай и масса других слов с таким корнем.
Кстати имеющем значение --верх.

Флаг он реет.
Редкий случай незнания даже фасмеровских, глупых, не то слово, определений.
рей не брус, это бревно, он всю жизнь круглым был.Рей или ре́я (нидерл. ra) — горизонтальное рангоутное дерево, подвешенное за середину при помощи боргов и бейфута к мачте или стеньге.
рейка, другое дело--профиль имеет.
в общем не все так просто.

Comment: Еще забыли  рейд, рейв, Рейгана, Рейкьявик и реестр
Слушайте, не нельзя ж все в одну кучу-то?!

>(нидерл. ra)    
  
В голланском есть слово ree - рея. 
ra - это двор (анг. yard)
Так называли всю конструкцию для "прогулок" на мачте, а не только горизонтральную планку.

https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra_%28zeil%29
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yard_%28sailing%29

К рейсу и прочему вашему набору, отношения не имеет никакого.

Вы хоть иногда проверяете источники. Можно ведь и на знающего напороться. )))

(Я два года жил в Голландии а до этого немного ходил под парусом, бизань от бушприта отличаю)

Comment: Вы хоть иногда проверяете источники. Можно ведь и на знающего напороться. )))

(Я два года жил в Голландии а до этого немного ходил под парусом, бизань от бушприта отличаю).

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется наоборот: изначально была рея, но позже это слово адаптировалось под брус. И стал рей, подобно брусу, мужского рода.

Comment: смотрите комментарий к моему ответу.